# Разбить на части список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите разбить на части список.

Нужно, чтобы часть была не больше 99 элементов.

И в последней части не должен остаться 1 элемент, минимум 2.

Comment: частей 2 или больше ?

Comment: Допустим список из 100 элементов. И что? Куда один-то девать? Переформулируйте, пожалуйста вопрос.

Comment: если до 99 элементов часть 1 если больше то 2 или больше. Если 100 элементов то можно разбить на 2 любые части главное условие чтобы 1 часть не больше 99

Comment: в каком виде должны быть выходные данные? консоль? список со списками? ещё что-то?

Comment: просто список списков

Answer (score 3):

1. делим длину списка на 99

например `1982 // 99 = 20`

получаем кол-во списков длиной 99 элементов

2. определяем длину последнего списка

например `1982 % 99 = 2`

3. если длина последнего списка равна 1, то длину предпоследнего списка делаем 98
4. списки из начального списка формируем через срезы

   ```
    new = old[first:last]
   ```

таким образом в универсальном решении у нас будет цикл от 0 до предпоследнего списка, затем формирование предпоследнего списка и формирование последнего списка